# Does the Nikon D5100 stop working if you don't use it for a while?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100

I bought my camera in 2012/2013. Two months ago I would use it to record a video. A few days ago I wanted to use it again. Between those times, I haven't touched the camera. Strangely enough the camera doesn't work now: the display doesn't go on. I can't take pictures or record videos. Only the tiny green light goes on if I switch the camera to on, signaling it is accessing the SD card. I made sure the battery and the charger are correct (I bought a pair of new batteries and a new charger).

Does the Nikon D5100 stop working if you don't use it for a while? How can I fix it?

Comment: No. Related yes. But not duplicate.

Comment: Pretending that it might be a "feature" of the camera to stop working after a while doesn't change the question that still is "what's wrong with my camera?". Instead, please update your other question if you have some new information. Or change this question to be clearly distinguishable from the other one. thank you.

Comment: But it does is not, hasn't maybe not going to be working? maybe, but hard to say...

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to always work.  The battery is the first thing to check, try recharging it, but maybe you already have.  If it does not turn on with a fresh battery, then it sounds like it needs service.